# Create key only if within intervall and add values of same keys

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have the following code

```
    avg_lat={}
    g_coords={}
    for year,lat,num,long in zip(years,latitudes,quantities,longitudes):
        if year in avg_lat: 
            avg_lat[year] += lat #Ignore avg_lat, this bit is irrelevant, but I gotta keep it for the code to work
            if 58.50>lat>56.83 and 17.83>long>15.26:
               g_coords[year]+=num
        else:
            avg_lat[year] = lat
            g_coords[year]=num
    return g_coords
```

Now my problem is that it's obviously making keys that aren't fullfiling the requirement, how can I change the code so that it only registers keys when it fulfills the requirment and then for nonunique keys add the values together? Note that I'm not allowed to use pandas either, only `numpy`

Edit: Here are some examples of what the arrays can look like and what I expect the result to be:

```
return years,,latitudes,quantites,longitudes
output: 
(array([2021, 2021, 2021, ..., 1996, 1996, 1996]),  array([59.0193253, 59.4408419, 59.2559116, ..., 55.5246801, 55.5234546,
       56.1633051]), array([1, 1, 1, ..., 2, 6, 1]), array([17.619529 , 18.6676653, 18.2598482, ..., 12.9141087, 12.9079911,
       14.903895 ]))
```

The requirement is
`if 58.50>lat>56.83 and 17.83>long>15.26: g_coords[year]+=num`. So in essence I want it to store the amount of observations of the year that are in a certain place.

````
latitudes=[58.60,57.0,55.9]
longitudes=[17.69,16.0,15.5]
quantites=[2,3,6]
print(g_coords)
output: (2021:5)```
````

Comment: Well if I remove it I get a KeyValue error, because there is no first entry for it to register.
It would've been fine if in the `if` block I had `g_coords[year]=num`, then it works fine, but doesn't add up the value of similar keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you need `avg_lat` for. But strictly addressing the question you ask in your post, you can do:

```
g_coords={}
for year,lat,num,long in zip(years,latitudes,quantities,longitudes):
    if 58.50>lat>56.83 and 17.83>long>15.26:
        if year not in g_coords:
            g_coords[year] = 0 #initialize with 0 if the key doesn't exist
        g_coords[year] += num
```

Comment: This is the answer! Solved! (I have the avg_lat for another part of the code and didn't care to find another way to write the first if statement to make it still functional

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from the standar library:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# outside of the loop
g_coords = defaultdict(int)
# inside the loop
g_coords['some_key']+=1
```

This way you don't have to initialize the keys and don't have to insert values with zeros, or num as you have stated in your code.